# Install Oracle 12c on window 7 32bit

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, 32-bit

Is there any manual or site on how to install oracle 12c on window 7 32 bit machine?
I already downloaded the software but majority for the sites is for only 64bit machine

Answer (score 1):

According to [OTN](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html), Oracle 12.1 and 12.2 is only available as "Microsoft Windows x64 (64-bit)" version. In general, there seems to be no 32-bit version for Linux and the other operating systems either.